# No taskbar and wifi after hard docking station ejection with Kubuntu

Tags: networking, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, screen

I am using Kubuntu on my Lenovo ThinkPad X230 together with a docking station. It connects two monitors and a wired internet connection.

Just a few minutes ago, I was too lazy to shut the device down and pulled it from the docking station while running.

After the screen on the notebook came back up, the taskbar is gone. The screen looks like the secondary screen on my two-monitor-setup. Also, the Wifi connection is non-functional. When I add panels, they appear on the second monitor (the one without taskbar) once I reconnect to the docking station.

**My hypothesis**: By pulling the device out the hard way, some config files (maybe of the KDE Plasma 5 Desktop) are messed up. So the notebook still thinkgs it is inserted in the docking station and shows the secondary monitor only including a deactivated wifi connection.

Can you help me fixing this problem?

I would be happy to provide more information on the problem if required!

Best wishes,
Mardy :-)

Answer (score 0):

### A. Repair

It might help to repair the file system. Boot from another drive (for example your Kubuntu install DVD disk or USB pendrive). Unmount the partition(s) and run *e2fsck* on the root partition (and the home partition too, if you have one).

```
sudo umount /dev/sdxn
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdxn
```

where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number.

Sometimes it is possible to identify bad files and fix them.

### B. Reinstall

If the quick-fix repair did not work, it is probably easiest (and takes least time) to

- Save all personal files (when booted from another drive).
- Maybe save the /home directory
- Reinstall Kubuntu (maybe using the saved /home directory in a separate partition)
- or Restore the personal files to the reinstalled system